# Probability of sequence with binary data

Tags: r, simulation, probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Say I have n balls, x blue and (n-x) red. If I draw the balls randomly one at a time, what is the probability of having a series of k blue balls drawn in a row?

Context, I am simulating golf rounds. I am curious what the probability is of having a streak of k+ birdies+ in a row. I am using a multinomial simulator to sim at the round level rather than hole by hole. So I am wanting to use the fact that I had x birdies+ out of 18, figure out the probability of a k+ streak existing, then just stick that probability into a binomial to record success/failure of achieving streak.
Right now I am just using the following function in R and it is not very fast (x is a vector of x+ birdies, one element for each player being simulated)

```
golf_streak <- function(x,k){
  test <- lapply(x, function(i) {sample(c(rep(1, i), rep(0, 18 - i))) })
  t <- lapply(test, rle)
  as.numeric(sapply(t, function(rl) any(rl$lengths[rl$values == 1] >= k)))

}
```

x-posted here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4719474/probability-of-sequence-with-binary-data

---

I still haven't found an exact solution, but I found a very efficient computation solution. For each value of k, I run my above code n times and store the number of successes for a very large n. This provides a fairly good estimate for the probability of a streak. I save these values in a csv to be uploaded as a data.frame and then join that table to get the probabilities of a streak. So I no longer need to compute on the fly. Would still be nice to get an exact answer though.

Comment: Running 3 loops can be reduced to one, e.g. `golf_streak <- function(x){unlist(lapply(x, function(i){rl <- rle(sample(c(rep(1, i), rep(0, 18 - i)))); rl$lengths[rl$values == 1]}))}`. Left out `k` cause it's not defined.

Comment: @AndreWildberg Thanks, I had hardcoded k as 3, but tried to generalize at the last second. I edited it to include k as an argument. With k=3, your example had ~4% reduction in time compared to mine. If I can get an exact formula, I'd expect it to perform 20-50x faster

Comment: It seems a strange problem *"given that I had `k` birdies in 18 holes, what is the probability that I had a streak of length `s` or more."* If you re-framed the problem with each hole as an independent event *"If I have probability `p` of getting a birdy and I shoot 18 holes, what is the probability I'll get a streak of length `s` or more?"* the math/simulations might get easier - [here's a related coin flip problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1409372/32504). But if you want a formula answer for your question as stated I'd suggest asking at math.stackexchange.com, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: (Also, I'd suggest being more consistent in terminology. Your first sentence uses `n` as the total number of balls, 18 for your golf case. But later you use `n` for the length of the streak. I'd suggest `n = 18` total balls, `k` birdies because in combinatorics `k` is the most frequent used variable for a number subset of `n`, and `s` for the streak length. Being consistent and adopting common practice will make it easier to quickly understand your question and go back and forth between code and problem statement.)

Comment: @GregorThomas I've gotten the two sites mixed up so many times... I thought I've seen discrete math questions on here but now that you mention it, it was probably SE. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: There's certainly overlap - sometimes someone will ask a discrete-math simulation question expecting code help, but instead get a closed-form mathematical solution. (I've answered more than a few questions over the years where someone describes a problem for the answer to be "you're describing matrix multiplication, do `A %*% B`".) But if you goal is a mathematical solution, then starting on the math site is a good idea.